# How to generate docker image path for FROM command

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile

When I create asp.net core project from scratch, the first line of Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim AS base
```

I need to change the platform to **ARM32v7**. I've checked [Docker Hub of Microsoft](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/) then I know what image tags I need to use:

```
2.2.3-stretch-slim-arm32v7, 2.2-stretch-slim-arm32v7, 2.2.3, 2.2, latest (Dockerfile)
```

Even though I did work as below, I don't understand how can it work without correct tag names?

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7 AS base
```

**My question is: how can I generate the image path to use for FROM command of Dockerfile?**

Thank you for help!

Comment: The stuff before the `:` is the actual image name, i.e. `microsoft/dotnet`. That piece is constant. The part after the `:` is the tag. You seem to already understand that you need to change the tag. You also already know what tag you need to use. Simply substitute the tag portion, and you're done.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I just added what I do, it works even though I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.3-stretch-slim-arm32v7 AS base
```

Comment: I tried this, it works. FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-stretch-slim-arm32v7 AS base
-> can you explain me why this works without correct tag names

Comment: It *is* a correct tag name? I mean it wouldn't work if it weren't. It's likely that whatever you're looking at doesn't present a full listing of all available tags.